# How to sort an array using JavaScript when an array has different dataTypes in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, typescript

I am fairly new to javascript so i am having problem sorting an array.
Say i have two arrays like this:

```
var mergedArray = result.Entities.concat(result.NonClickablePaths);
var allPaths = result.AllPaths;
```

The data in both arrays look like this:

```
mergedArray  = [{obj1}, {obj2}, 'xyz'];
AllPaths =  [ 'abc', 'xyz', 'wxy'];
```

Here, The data mentioned in AllPaths array does exist in mergedArray objects like this: `obj1.coords = 'abc'` and `obj2.coords = 'wxy'.`
As you can see, mergedArray currently has obj1 on index 0,  obj2 on index 1 and string xyz on final index. now i want to sort `mergedArray` based on the values order in AllPaths.

Is this sorting functionality achievable?

The expected outcome of this sort functionality will be to sort the mergedArray by checking the order of values in the AllPaths and order them likewise:
Output:
`mergedArray = [{obj1}, 'xyz', {obj2}];`

**Things I have tried this step but failed to achieve this desired functionality:

Step :**

```
mergedArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aCoord = (typeof a === 'object') ? a.coords : a;
  var bCoord = (typeof b === 'object') ? b.coords : b;
  return allPaths.indexOf(aCoord) - allPaths.indexOf(bCoord);
});
```

Using this js built in sortFunction to check the coords , i checked the data structure after sorting it remains same, no changes at all.

**Note:** I couldn't think of any steps to sort this array in this fashion. Any guidance will be appreciated. Thank you all.

Comment: Your code works perfectly. Why don't you think it works? Please provide a self-contained example of what you think isn't working

Comment: Sorry Andrew, it was just a cache issue with my browser. It worked fine. hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked you code, and the sorting seems to work fine with the data you provide (see the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5tr6ou72/), I did some cleanup like using `const` and using `||` to shorten the tertiary operator).
My guess it that the structure of `obj1` and `obj2` might be different then you expect, since

```
mergedArray  = [{obj1}, {obj2}, 'xyz'];
```

is shorthand for

```
mergedArray = [{
  obj1: {
    coords: 'abc'
  },
  obj2: {
    coords: 'wxy'
  },
  'xyz'
]
```

In case that is the actual structure of the array, you need to do access the parent object, to access `coords`, e.g. by doing

```
const aCoord = typeof a == 'object' ? Object.values(a).find(e => !!e.coords).coords : a;
```

Comment: Thank you Micro. It seems to be it was because of the cache in browser when i made the changes to my code. I cleared the cache and ran it and it works as expected. thanks.